# How to mix destructive and non-destructive modifiers to maintain vertex order for mesh-cache?

Tags: mesh, shape-keys, instances

Say I have an instanced model (duplicated with alt+D) and I add a meshcache modifier with a .mdd or .pc2 file loading a different version of the model. Will this break the instancing and cause it to count as a different model for memory usage in rendering?

How about different shapekeys on instanced models?

How about modifiers that actually change the number of verts, like boolean or solidify?

Comment: This seems a bit of an odd question, why would it break?

Comment: I'm not sure. If it's the same object, but the vertices are re-ordered, is that still the same object? I'm pretty sure some modifiers break it, like boolean and solidify.

Comment: The question doesn't mention boolean-modifier - suggest to ask edit it to make it more spesific.

Comment: Good call. Updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicating mesh data won't change its vertex order, so to answer your first question - yes this is supported.

As for destructive modifiers (boolean, decimate, build... etc). These will change vertex count and order, not for the mesh-datablock, only within the modifier stack.
So destructive modifiers **must** be applied after Mesh-Cache modifier, for this to work as expected.